# PM2 graceful stop in windows via trigger

Tags: triggers, pm2

I'm using PM2 in windows and would like to stop an app gracefully.  In my js code, i have this:

```
const pmx = require("pmx"); // 
pmx.action("sigterm",(reply) => {
        stop(
            () => reply({success:true }),
            () => reply({success:false}))
})
```

and if I start my script like this:

```
pm2 start MyScript.js --name MyScript
```

then when I call this, the current running instance shuts down quite gracefully:

```
pm2 trigger MyScript sigterm
```

Of course, PM2 dutifully starts up a new instance which have to shut down quite ungracefully like so:

```
pm2 stop MyScript 
[insert sound of un-closed resources crashing here.]
```

Is there a way to have PM2 sent a trigger when calling `pm2 stop`?

BTW, I do know about `--no-autorestart` but that's not what I want because I **do** want PM2 to restart the processes when it crashes.  I just want a way to gracefully stop my app in windows.

Answer (score 0):

I've settled on the cludgy:

```
// PM2 initiated shutdown
pmx.action("stop",(my_name,reply) => {
    graceful_shutdown().then{ () => {
        reply({success:true });
        fs.execSync("pm2 stop " +my_name);
        process.exit();
    }).catch(() => reply({success:false}))
})
```

combined with

```
> pm2 trigger MyScript stop "MyScript"
```

but I'm eager to hear a better solution.

Comment: +1 I'm seeking a better solution https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3467. I feel the way is wrong, because if I use pm2 to start a python script, python does not understand pmx.